# Which of Landau's books are suited for undergraduates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Seeing how well-received Landau's books are, I want to know if any of them are suited for undergraduates.

Comment: My sophomore advanced mechanics class used Landau and Lifschitz. I found their quantum book very enlightening. Non-current standard notation made the elasticity book more difficult to use than hoped for. I have found in chatting with people that they either love them or loathe them - seems to depend on your learning style.

Comment: This very much depends on the student and time one wants to invest. In general Landau's book are quite heavy and requires a lot of effort to go through. I remember in the Statistical Mechanics book derivation of one equation from the preceding one, where he calls trivial, was taking pages of calculations. In many cases these derivations actually end up being exam questions.

Comment: I have met students who could read them like children's fairytales and to me the books seemed uselessly complex at times. 30 years later I got myself a copy of the mechanics Volume and found it highly enlightening. I read the entire thing in an afternoon and felt refreshed.